# React Создание кастомного progressbar с анимацией

Tags: javascript, reactjs, progress-bar, create-react-app

Пробую создать кастомный `progress` элемент на Реакте на основе [вот этого примера](http://jsfiddle.net/pantyuhind/vdkw3dvh/3/)
На выходе у меня получился [вот такой компонент](https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-dust-vcg8h?file=/src/App.js)

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const coins = 26000;
const rankCoinsToNextLevel = 40000;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ProfileProgressbar
      coins={coins}
      rankCoinsToNextLevel={rankCoinsToNextLevel}
    />
  );
}

function ProfileProgressbar(props) {
  const { coins, rankCoinsToNextLevel } = props;

  console.log("coins = ", coins);

  return (
    <div className="profile_rank__elem">
      <p className="profile_rank__text">Повышение через:</p>
      <div className="progress">
        <progress
          max={rankCoinsToNextLevel}
          value={setTimeout(function () {
            this.value = coins;
          }, 500)}
        />
        <div className="progress-bg">
          <div className="progress-bar" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```css
.profile_rank__elem {
     position: relative;
     width: calc(100% - 68px);
     text-align: center;
}
 @media (min-width: 450px) {
     .profile_rank__elem {
         width: calc(100% - 90px);
    }
}
 .profile_rank__text {
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     top: -34px;
     transform: translateX(-50%);
     font-size: 12px;
     color: #d1d0e5;
     text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
 @media (min-width: 450px) {
     .profile_rank__text {
         font-size: 14px;
    }
}
 .progress progress[value="0"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 0%;
}
 .progress progress[value="1"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 1%;
}
 .progress progress[value="2"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 2%;
}
 .progress progress[value="3"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 3%;
}
 .progress progress[value="4"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 4%;
}
 .progress progress[value="5"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 5%;
}
 .progress progress[value="6"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 6%;
}
 .progress progress[value="7"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 7%;
}
 .progress progress[value="8"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 8%;
}
 .progress progress[value="9"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 9%;
}
 .progress progress[value="10"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 10%;
}
 .progress progress[value="11"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 11%;
}
 .progress progress[value="12"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 12%;
}
 .progress progress[value="13"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 13%;
}
 .progress progress[value="14"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 14%;
}
 .progress progress[value="15"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 15%;
}
 .progress progress[value="16"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 16%;
}
 .progress progress[value="17"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 17%;
}
 .progress progress[value="18"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 18%;
}
 .progress progress[value="19"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 19%;
}
 .progress progress[value="20"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 20%;
}
 .progress progress[value="21"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 21%;
}
 .progress progress[value="22"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 22%;
}
 .progress progress[value="23"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 23%;
}
 .progress progress[value="24"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 24%;
}
 .progress progress[value="25"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 25%;
}
 .progress progress[value="26"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 26%;
}
 .progress progress[value="27"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 27%;
}
 .progress progress[value="28"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 28%;
}
 .progress progress[value="29"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 29%;
}
 .progress progress[value="30"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 30%;
}
 .progress progress[value="31"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 31%;
}
 .progress progress[value="32"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 32%;
}
 .progress progress[value="33"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 33%;
}
 .progress progress[value="34"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 34%;
}
 .progress progress[value="35"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 35%;
}
 .progress progress[value="36"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 36%;
}
 .progress progress[value="37"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 37%;
}
 .progress progress[value="38"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 38%;
}
 .progress progress[value="39"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 39%;
}
 .progress progress[value="40"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 40%;
}
 .progress progress[value="41"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 41%;
}
 .progress progress[value="42"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 42%;
}
 .progress progress[value="43"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 43%;
}
 .progress progress[value="44"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 44%;
}
 .progress progress[value="45"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 45%;
}
 .progress progress[value="46"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 46%;
}
 .progress progress[value="47"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 47%;
}
 .progress progress[value="48"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 48%;
}
 .progress progress[value="49"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 49%;
}
 .progress progress[value="50"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 50%;
}
 .progress progress[value="51"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 51%;
}
 .progress progress[value="52"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 52%;
}
 .progress progress[value="53"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 53%;
}
 .progress progress[value="54"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 54%;
}
 .progress progress[value="55"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 55%;
}
 .progress progress[value="56"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 56%;
}
 .progress progress[value="57"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 57%;
}
 .progress progress[value="58"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 58%;
}
 .progress progress[value="59"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 59%;
}
 .progress progress[value="60"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 60%;
}
 .progress progress[value="61"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 61%;
}
 .progress progress[value="62"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 62%;
}
 .progress progress[value="63"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 63%;
}
 .progress progress[value="64"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 64%;
}
 .progress progress[value="65"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 65%;
}
 .progress progress[value="66"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 66%;
}
 .progress progress[value="67"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 67%;
}
 .progress progress[value="68"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 68%;
}
 .progress progress[value="69"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 69%;
}
 .progress progress[value="70"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 70%;
}
 .progress progress[value="71"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 71%;
}
 .progress progress[value="72"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 72%;
}
 .progress progress[value="73"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 73%;
}
 .progress progress[value="74"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 74%;
}
 .progress progress[value="75"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 75%;
}
 .progress progress[value="76"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 76%;
}
 .progress progress[value="77"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 77%;
}
 .progress progress[value="78"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 78%;
}
 .progress progress[value="79"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 79%;
}
 .progress progress[value="80"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 80%;
}
 .progress progress[value="81"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 81%;
}
 .progress progress[value="82"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 82%;
}
 .progress progress[value="83"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 83%;
}
 .progress progress[value="84"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 84%;
}
 .progress progress[value="85"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 85%;
}
 .progress progress[value="86"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 86%;
}
 .progress progress[value="87"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 87%;
}
 .progress progress[value="88"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 88%;
}
 .progress progress[value="89"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 89%;
}
 .progress progress[value="90"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 90%;
}
 .progress progress[value="91"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 91%;
}
 .progress progress[value="92"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 92%;
}
 .progress progress[value="93"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 93%;
}
 .progress progress[value="94"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 94%;
}
 .progress progress[value="95"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 95%;
}
 .progress progress[value="96"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 96%;
}
 .progress progress[value="97"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 97%;
}
 .progress progress[value="98"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 98%;
}
 .progress progress[value="99"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 99%;
}
 .progress progress[value="100"] ~ .progress-bg .progress-bar {
     width: 100%;
}
 .progress {
     position: relative;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 .progress progress {
     position: absolute;
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     overflow: hidden;
     left: -777px;
}
 .progress-bg {
     background: #e6e9ed;
     position: relative;
     height: 8px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     overflow: hidden;
}
 @keyframes progress_bar {
     0% {
         background-position: 0 0;
    }
     100% {
         background-position: -40px 0;
    }
}
 .progress-bar {
     overflow: hidden;
     background: #ac92ec;
     height: 100%;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 0;
     -webkit-transition: width 1s linear;
     -moz-transition: width 1s linear;
     -ms-transition: width 1s linear;
     transition: width 1s linear;
}
 .progress-bar:after {
     -webkit-animation: progress_bar 0.8s linear infinite;
     -moz-animation: progress_bar 0.8s linear infinite;
     -ms-animation: progress_bar 0.8s linear infinite;
     -o-animation: progress_bar 0.8s linear infinite;
     animation: progress_bar 0.8s linear infinite;
     background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
     background-image: -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
     background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 25%, transparent 25%, transparent 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 50%, rgba(255, 255, 255, .15) 75%, transparent 75%, transparent);
     -webkit-background-size: 40px 40px;
     background-size: 40px 40px;
     position: absolute;
     content: '';
     top: 0;
     left: 0;
     width: 100%;
     height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

По задумке атрибуты `max` и `value` будут наполняться динамическими значениями параметров, которые приходят из других компонентов, но проблема в том что значение `value` как-то не доходит как надо, даже если увеличить время срабатывания. Собственно и анимация не показывается. Не могу разобраться как показывать анимацию и собственно перерендывать компонент всякий раз когда он вызывается и значения порога и значения были изменены

Answer (score 2, accepted):

проблема в том что ты неправильно задавал значение для тега `<progress>` для такого более "Реактово" будет использовать хуки: `useState` `useEffect`

```
function ProfileProgressbar(props) {
  const { coins, rankCoinsToNextLevel } = props;
  const [data, setData ] = useState(0);
  
  useEffect(()=>{setTimeout(function () {
    setData(coins)
  }, 500)},[])

  return (
    <div className="profile_rank__elem">
      <p className="profile_rank__text">Повышение через:</p>
      <div className="progress">
        <progress max={rankCoinsToNextLevel} value={data} />
        <div className="progress-bg">
          <div className="progress-bar" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как добиться анимации движения ползунка ? Насколько я вижу что setTimeout не отрабатывает тут так же как в изначальном примере

Comment: это можно сделать при помощи css подробнее тут:(https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp) [ENG]
Пример: https://codepen.io/evawythien/embed/jegRxN?default-tab=result&theme-id=dark#result-box

Comment: Спасибо, удалось разобраться в чем была проблема с анимацией. CSS дергал для неё значение из параметра value; Добавил к компленту значения data-value =(value*100/max) и дергал это значение и все заработало